# Using Heroku to deploy a Spring Boot application that has dependencies to Maven submodules

Tags: spring-boot, maven, heroku

I'd like to deploy a Spring Boot application - with Heroku - that is part to a multi-module Maven project and that references one of those submodules:

```
$ ls .
api/
models/
Procfile
pom.xml
```

The master parent `pom.xml` has the following modules:

```
<modules>
  <module>models</module>
  <module>api</module>
</modules>
```

The `api` project references the `models` module with:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>models</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And the `Procfile` contents are:

```
web: java -Dserver.port=$PORT -jar $PATH_TO_JAR
```

Now, when I execute the `git push heroku master` command, I receive this error:

```
remote: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project api: 
Could not resolve dependencies for project com.test:api:jar:1.0: 
Could not find artifact com.test:models:jar:1.0 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
```

How can I properly resolve the local submodule dependency?

Answer (score 0):

Heroku builds the Maven reactor from scratch (upon git push) and it fails to find the `api` dependency because it is not in the local Maven nor in the Maven central.
Locally you would `mvn install` the sub-module first or use a `system` scope.

You can keep the same architecture if you deploy the application with [Heroku Docker](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/deploying-with-docker).

The Dockerfile packages the SpringBoot jar file you create locally:

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:latest
RUN mkdir -p /software
ADD target/mySpringBoot.jar /software/mySpringBoot.jar

CMD java -Dserver.port=$PORT $JAVA_OPTS -jar /software/mySpringBoot.jar
```

Create the SpringBoot application jar file then buiod/push the image to Heroku

```
# build project locally (ie Springboot jar file)
mvn clean package

# build/push to Docker
heroku container:push web -a myapp
heroku container:release web -a myapp
```

Don't forget to log into the Heroku Docker registry (`heroku container:login`), only necessary once.